# Marshmellow issue with large SD card as internal storage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, insufficient-memory, motorola-moto-g

(this was posted in the thread [insufficient storage even with marshmallow sd card formatted for internal space and plenty of space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138737/insufficient-storage-even-with-marshmallow-sd-card-formatted-for-internal-space/165023#165023) which is a discussion about this same problem, but for some reason this got deleted... dont understand this.  Now I opened a new question)

Today I inserted a brand new 64GB fast SD card (Sandisk extreme U3) in my MotoG 2nd generation, as I was constantly hitting the internal storage barrier. I formatted it as "internal storage" also called Adopted storage I believe.

I was expecting to see a total size of 64 GB of "memory" to be available, and not having to bother anymore with choosing between internal mem and SD cards. So I am now still puzzled why I still see both separate, and still hit the limits on storage space... I thought Android would handle this fully in background, so the user would see 1 big memory. What I don't understand is that I still get the "not enough space" error and why then I would have to manually move apps or data between Internal memory...

When I check the storage, I see Android 2.5 GB, Internal memory 4.6 of 5.5 used, Sandisk SD card almost all free (58GB)

anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can't be stored on SdCard. The only way to do that is rooting the phone and use apps like [Link2sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=tr) or adopting SD card if you have Android 6+. [Here](http://www.modaco.com/news/android/heres-how-to-configure-adoptable-storage-on-your-s7-s7-edge-r1632/) is how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I DID "adopt" the SD card, like I clearly described in my first post.  I expected to see 1 large space, but that clearly is not the case.   So, I don think this "big new thing" on Android 6 is not really very useful.   I tried moving applications to the SD, but many cannot be moved

Comment: Than you done something wrong. Of course it shows as two different spaces, otherwise how would you know when apps are on SD card. What error you get when you try to move app. Did you migrated data on adopted card?

Comment: well, I expected that both storages would be managed in the background by Android, similar to a Win Swap file, where windows takes care of swapping between ram (internal storage) and disk (external storage, like my SD).

Comment: (sorry for the multiple messages, but each time I hit enter the message gets posted).  Yes, I did migrate my data (but minimal result: 250 mb).  I am not getting an error, but on many applications, I do not have the possibility to move it to SD.  Some yes (and those work) but many dont give the option to move

Comment: If you adopted it it should offer you moving for every single app. Provide a screenshot from storage menu in settings and open adopted space and take a ss, and addnit to question

Comment: http://i66.tinypic.com/124jzbp.jpg
Here are the 4 screen shots you asked (sorry, is in my local language, but you will recognize the format for sure).   upper left: all storage, upper right: SD card details, lower left: application now in Internal Memory but with the option to move it (genius scan as example), lower right: application where I do not get the possibility to move it (as most standard android things, but many other apps as well)

Comment: Well everything seems fine, I don' know why there isn't an option to move. As default you can't move preinstalled apps, those which are came with stock rom, but I don't think that uber was pre installed. However try cleaning all cache and rebooting, if that not help then format sd as external and adopt it again. If even after that there isn't option to move to adopted space for not pre installed apps, then it's probably up to software. Which device you own?

Comment: Moto G, 2nd gen with 8 GB internal mem only, hence why I wanted to expand my memory (was constantly hitting the limits)

Comment: I don't know then, as I said try formating it back to fat32 and adopt it again and than reboot. And are you sure that apps that cannot be moved are not system apps?

Comment: I tried reformatting back to normal SD card, reboot, and then reformatted the SD card as Internal storage (adopted).   Situation is exactly the same: several non-system apps do not offer the possibility to move.   Such as: Dropbox app, Tripadvisor app, K-9 mail app, GoPro app, Soundhound app, Uber app, etc....  for sure not system apps.